# Ciclo Activity android

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-activity, android-fragment

Meu app possui **4** `Activitys`.
Quando chego na `Activity` **número 4** o usuário tem opção de voltar para `Activity` **número 2** que esta em `onStop()`.
O problema é que quando volto para `Activity` **número 2** ela executa novamente o `onCreate()`, criando uma **nova** `Activity`.
Eu preciso que execute somente o `onStart()`.

```java
 imgeditarproduto.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ProdutosActivity.class);
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
```

Resumindo quero voltar da `Activity` **número 4** para `Activity` **número 2**.

Answer (score 1):

Criei um variável Global que retorna um `boolean`, toda vez que a Activity executar o método `onRestart()` executar um `if` verificando o status da variável  caso a mesma seja `true` executa novamente o método `finish()`

```java
   @Override
    protected void onRestart() {
        super.onRestart();

           if(Globais.result == true){
               Globais.result = false;
               finish();
           }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Outra forma de resolver essa questão é você pode chamar da **activity 3** para **activity 4** usando o `startActivityForResult` e na **activity 4**, quando matar a instância da classe, irá cair no método `onActivityResult` antes do `onResume` e do `onStart`.

Lembre-se que o método `onActivityResult` será sobrescrito na **activity 3** e a partir daí você pode fazer o que quiser, como por exemplo chamar o `finish()` voltando assim para **activity 2**.

Answer (score 0):

A linha `intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);` realmente é necessária? Experimente tirar ela.